# Как удалить пакеты, игнорируя отуствующие?

Tags: linux, manjaro

Я пишу скрипт для автонастройки Manjaro под себя и столкнулся с проблемой:

Если мне нужно установить пакеты, я выполняю такую команду:

> sudo pacman -Syu --needed **список пакетов**

В результате, если какой-то из пакетов уже установлен, то ничего страшного, установка всё равно будет выполнена.

Но я никак не пойму, как написать аналогичную команду на удаление, чтобы удалялись все пакеты из списка, даже если в этот список включены уже удалённые или ещё не установленные пакеты, чтобы не было ошибок типа "такой-то пакет не найден".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qeq список пакетов)
```